# Getting Token/Bearer using openid-connect with Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, openid-connect

I'm working on an API, i need to get a token access using PostMan, it's an openid connect token i've tried to get using a GET Method and a POST Method but the result is the same i always have Invalid Request , with missing form parameter for the grant type key.
As you can see bellow the grand type is already setted but not working.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks
[image: PostMan Example]

Answer (score 1):

As a guess, as I don't know the full details, I would have thought it would need to be something like this:

[image: Postman]

Add the details for the `client_id`, `client_secret` and `grant_type` to the request body. These should be placed in the `x-www-form-urlencoded` option.

As I don't know the full details, I'll be happy to update the answer if more are provided.

Comment: If you're happy with this, can you accept the answer and close out the question please.